# Generate presigned url for uploading file to google storage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a image from front end to google storage using javascript ajax functionality. I need a presigned url that the server would generate which would provide authentication to my frontend to upload a blob.
How can I generate a presigned url when using my local machine.

Previously for aws s3 I would do :

```
pp = s3.generate_presigned_post(
            Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key='folder1/' + file_name,  
            ExpiresIn=20  # seconds
        )
```

When generating a signed url for a user to just view a file stored on google storage I do :

```
    bucket = settings.CLIENT.bucket(settings.BUCKET_NAME)
    blob_name = 'folder/img1.jpg'
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version='v4',
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
        method='GET')
```

Comment: Is your question about how to generate the url locally? Then you should refer to the [authentication guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) and set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var locally when you run your script.

Comment: No its not about generating locally. Its about how my server can generate a url that can be used by users in front end to upload a file to storage directly from browser.

Comment: Then all you need is to change your code snippet's method from GET to PUT or POST. The docs for the feature are confusing, so also take care of this: 1. you need to [instantiate the client from a credentials json](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/core/auth.html#service-accounts), 2. credentials should use a service account with permission to create objects in a target bucket, 3. you need to [configure CORS with `gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors) to allow front-end calls – if something goes wrong, try setting `responseHeaders` to `'*'`

Comment: Is there a specific dictionary/Json format for sending post data to GCP storage? Do u have a working Ajax preferably Axios frontend example ? E.g.: {key: ‘’ , data :’’ }

Comment: Should be as simple as axios.put(presignedUrl, file)

Comment: Adding cors and service account key made it work on my local machine. But when I run the same code on app engine, i get an error -- " you need a private key to sign credentials". I also gave read write access to app engine's default service account for the bucket

Comment: Yea, you need to have that json file on app engine and initiate the client from it as i wrote above. Only the json file has a key that can sign the url, default alp engine credentials don't have it. Now, delivering the json file to app engine might be a pain because it shouldn't be checked in into the repo.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/ Docs say app engine file system is not writable. How did you do it? Also docs say its not advisable to write to app engine. Isnt app engine supposed to use default service account inherently?

Comment: True, for app engine standard it's probably not doable – my workaround is for GAE flex. Still, you can decrypt into memory. Default service account doesn't help because it has no signing key attached to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spent 100$ on google support and 2 weeks of my time to finally find a solution.

```
client = storage.Client() # works on app engine standard without any credentials requirements
```

But if you want to use `generate_signed_url()` function then you need service account Json key.

Every app engine standard has a default service account. ( You can find it in IAM/service account). Create a key for that default sv account and download the key ('sv_key.json') in json format. Store that key in your Django project right next to app.yaml file. Then do the following :

```
from google.cloud import storage
CLIENT = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('sv_key.json')
bucket = CLIENT.bucket('bucket_name_1')
blob = bucket.blob('img1.jpg') # name of file to be saved/uploaded to storage
pp = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version='v4',
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
    method='POST')
```

This will work on your local machine and GAE standard. WHen you deploy your app to GAE, sv_key.json also gets deployed with Django project and hence it works.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's important to add the json to .gitignore in this case

Comment: If we put the json in .gitignore , how would GAE access the private json key? I can store it in secret manager, but the func `storage.client.from_service_account_json()` needs a json path. It doesnt take the json content

Comment: Haven't used GAE, but using Heroku the way I would solve this is to have the Access Key JSON-content as a string in an environment variable. Then in the app startup, have a function that creates the gcreds.json file from that environment-variable.

This way there is no access key included in the repository, and you can change the access key using the ENV-variable, and restart the app without doing a commit/deploy

Answer (score 1):

Editing my answer as I didn't understand the problem you were facing.

Taking a look at the comments thread in the question, as @Nick Shebanov stated, there's one possibility to accomplish what are you trying to when using GAE with flex environment.

I have been trying to do the same with GAE Standard environment with no luck so far. At this point, I would recommend opening a feature request at the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) so this gets somehow implemented.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, and apparently @Aseem is already using an example from docs

Answer (score 0):

- Create a service account private key and store it in SecretManager (SM).
- In settings.py retrieve that key from SecretManager and store it in a constant - `SV_ACCOUNT_KEY`
- Override Client() class func `from_service_account_json()` to take json key content instead of a path to json file. This way we dont have to have a json file in our file system (locally, cloudbuild or in GAE). we can just get private key contents from SM anytime anywhere.

**settings.py**

```
secret = SecretManager()
SV_ACCOUNT_KEY = secret.access_secret_data('SV_ACCOUNT_KEY')
```

**signed_url_mixin.py**

```
import datetime
import json

from django.conf import settings
from google.cloud.storage.client import Client
from google.oauth2 import service_account


class CustomClient(Client):
    @classmethod
    def from_service_account_json(cls, json_credentials_path, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Copying everything from base func (from_service_account_json). 
        Instead of passing json file for private key, we pass the private key
        json contents directly (since we cannot save a file on GAE).
        Since its not properly written, we cannot just overwrite a class or a
        func, we have to rewrite this entire func.
        """
        if "credentials" in kwargs:
            raise TypeError("credentials must not be in keyword arguments")
        credentials_info = json.loads(json_credentials_path)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            credentials_info
        )
        if cls._SET_PROJECT:
            if "project" not in kwargs:
                kwargs["project"] = credentials_info.get("project_id")

        kwargs["credentials"] = credentials
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)


class _SignedUrlMixin:
    bucket_name = settings.BUCKET_NAME
    CLIENT = CustomClient.from_service_account_json(settings.SV_ACCOUNT_KEY)
    exp_min = 4  # expire minutes

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bucket = self.CLIENT.bucket(self.bucket_name)

    def _signed_url(self, file_name, method):
        blob = self.bucket.blob(file_name)
        signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            version='v4',
            expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=self.exp_min),
            method=method
        )
        return signed_url


class GetSignedUrlMixin(_SignedUrlMixin):
    """
    A GET url to view file on CS
    """

    def get_signed_url(self, file_name):
        """
        :param file_name: name of file to be retrieved from CS.
            xyz/f1.pdf
        :return: GET signed url
        """
        method = 'GET'
        return self._signed_url(file_name, method)


class PutSignedUrlMixin(_SignedUrlMixin):
    """
    A PUT url to make a put req to upload a file to CS
    """

    def put_signed_url(self, file_name):
        """
        :file_name: xyz/f1.pdf
        """
        method = 'PUT'
        return self._signed_url(file_name, method)
```